# F# Seq.FindIndex starting from the end not the beginning?

Tags: f#

I have this array

```
let myArray = [1;2;3;5;2;7]
```

I want to get the number 4, not 1 for `Seq.FindIndex(fun x -> x=2) myArray`
I can reverse the array. However I was hoping there is a `Seq.FindIndexReverse` function....

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As not very "functional" but effective solution you can use [Array.LastIndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a749h1h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: What's not functional about that? It's just as functional as any Seq, List, or Array function that doesn't mutate the input.

Answer (score 2):

If reversing the array doesn't cut it for you, how about you write one yourself?

```
let findLastIndex f arr = 
    let rec inner f arr idx = 
      match idx with
      | _ when idx >= 0 ->
         if f (arr.[idx])
            then Some idx
            else inner arr f (idx - 1)
      | _ -> None
    inner f arr (Array.length arr - 1)
```

Didn't test it, but something like this should work.

By the way, you gave a list, not an array in your example. You define array literals with `[| |]`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in function for that, but you can combine your way to it easily:

```
[1;2;3;5;2;7] |> List.rev |> List.findIndex (fun x -> x = 2)
```

However, this **still returns 1**, because the second-to-last element is *also* `1`.

BTW, your list is a *list*, not an *array*, but it would be similar for arrays:

```
[|1;2;3;5;2;7|] |> Array.rev |> Array.findIndex (fun x -> x = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is quite late, but it might be useful for anyone else coming across this:

In F# 4.0 a method called `findIndexBack` was added for `Array`, `List` and `Seq`. This should return 4 for your function.

It's not documented on MSDN/GitHub, but the commit is on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/commit/4b52be7812360e6f562238d3c0e06576513dbeb9) and it appears in Visual Studio's Intellisense.